# Installing Hue on a Ambari cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hue, ambari

I have a Ambari cluster to manage my hadoop/spark jobs. I want to schedule my workflows using oozie editor. Hue is the most popular and easy to use one. How do I install hue on top of an existing hadoop cluster managed by Ambari.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hue is a service created by Cloudera. You cannot install it using Ambari, but you can download a package with Hue and install it based on official documentation. You should check this article - [Installing Hue 3.9 on HDP 2.3](http://gethue.com/hadoop-hue-3-on-hdp-installation-tutorial/)

Comment: The link you have shared clearly states that it doesn't support Oozie and spark workflows and only file browser etc basic functionality - doesn't help.

Comment: Did you see this article? Is shows how to install Hue on a cluster and configure Oozie service for scheduling workflows. The only thing you have to do is change Oozie host in hue.ini (Hue conf file). Then you can create Oozie workflows and coordinators.

Comment: Quoting from this article :

"Features confirmed to work in partial or complete fashion:

• Hive/Beeswax
• File Browser
• HDFS FACL Manager
• HBase Cluster Browser
• Job Browser

Still working on debugging/integrating Pig/Oozie!

Spark is on my to do list as well."

Comment: Did follow the steps and installed Hue. However, it is quite slow the Hue UI...seems to take a long time for any click actions on it...The system from which I am accessing is under same subnet so not a network speed or lag issue. Any pointers on that? thanks.